# How to show a message box in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am starting to develop a plugin for Qgis using python, which i am very new at, and would like to view some results of variables by displaying a message in QGIS. How can I do this?

Comment: Isn't Plugins->Python_console enough for you?

Comment: The Python console isn't really meant for that.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show a message box with some values.

Comment: Yes, I would like to show a message box with some values

Answer (score 12):

```
some_variable = feature.geometry()   

QMessageBox.information(None, "DEBUG:", str(some_variable))
```

Comment: How come this won´t work as a class while running it as sys import-script in the console editor?

Answer (score 4):

Another good option is the message log.

```
from qgis.core import QgsMessageLog

QgsMessageLog.logMessage("message")
```