# How to keep the same name in the entry of the script (QGIS 2.14) output file?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler

For example, I have a raster called "raster_img.tiff". I use it as input in QGIS script and want it to be in output file called the same name like input + new.

```
##Input_raster1=raster
##Band_raster1=output raster
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import os
from osgeo.gdalconst import *
import numpy
import sys
import osr
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
ds = gdal.Open(Input_raster1, GA_ReadOnly)
dst_ds_red = driver.Create(Band_raster1, ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize, 1, GDT_Float32)
dst_ds_red.SetProjection( ds.GetProjection())
geotransform = ds.GetGeoTransform()
if not geotransform is None:
  st_ds_red.SetGeoTransform( geotransform )

bandList = []
band = ds.GetRasterBand(2)
data = band.ReadAsArray()
bandList.append(data)

rasterlayer_red = numpy.zeros((ds.RasterYSize, ds.RasterXSize), dtype=numpy.float32)
for i in range (0, ds.RasterXSize):
  for j in range (0, ds.RasterYSize):

    RED = (float(bandList[0][j][i]))
    rasterlayer_red[j][i] = RED
dst_ds_red.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(rasterlayer_red)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try changing `##Band_raster1=output raster` to `##Band_raster1=folder` as an output folder and use `os.path.basename(Input_raster1)` to get the filename of the input raster:

```
##Input_raster1=raster
##Band_raster1=folder
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import os
from osgeo.gdalconst import *
import numpy
import sys
import osr
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
ds = gdal.Open(Input_raster1, GA_ReadOnly)
# Get filename of input raster
result = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(Input_raster1))[0] + "_new.tif"
dst_ds_red = driver.Create(Band_raster1 + "/" + result, ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize, 1, GDT_Float32)
dst_ds_red.SetProjection( ds.GetProjection())
geotransform = ds.GetGeoTransform()
if not geotransform is None:
  st_ds_red.SetGeoTransform( geotransform )
...
```

Comment: thank. it is exactly what i wanted .just a curiosity, if I would have the result output directly open QGIS how can I do

Comment: @Dokpe - You can have a look at the docs [Loading Raster Layers](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#raster-layers) where you could use the following at the end of your script: `iface.addRasterLayer("/path/to/raster/file.tif", "layer name you like")`.  So I think the following should work: `iface.addRasterLayer(Band_raster1 + "/" + result, result)`.

Comment: when i try this message come "NameError: name 'iface' is not defined"

Comment: @Dokpe - Make sure `from qgis.utils import iface` is still in your script. If the error persists, try using `iface.addRasterLayer(Band_raster1 + "/" + result, "result")`.

Comment: Sorry i do a mistake . forget "i" when i insert "from gqis.utils import face"

Comment: @ Joseph may be you could help me to find the way to show a message from the processing progress to the user.

Comment: @Dokpe - You should probably ask this as a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and add more details on what you are looking for. You could have a look at this post: [How to show a message box in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37426/how-to-show-a-message-box-in-qgis).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the os.path.splitext method and string manipulation e.g.

```
import os
in_rast = r"in_raster.tif" # input path

# Next you can split the file extension from the file name 
in_parts = os.path.splitext(in_rast)
```

The variable *in_parts* is a tuple with two string elements. The first is the file name 'in_raster', and the second is the extension '.tif'.

Now you can create a new name by appending '_new' to your file name, then append the extension to give you your new output path:

```
# continuing from above

new_name = in_parts[0] + '_new' # in_raster_new
new_path = new_name + in_parts[1] # in_raster_new.tif
```

This method will work regardless of the input file extensions, with the output file always being of the same data type. If you have other purposes which involve saving to a different file type then the follwing would work:

```
new_ext = '.png' # note the period is included
new_name = in_parts[0] + '_new' # in_raster_new
new_path = new_name + new_ext # in_raster_new.png
```